# Are there CUD operations in Hibernate thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

Could you please explain how CUD operations in Hibernate work with multithreading?
And are they threadsafe?
For example, two threads create users in same time, what will be with id? Is there any synchronization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to consider the hibernate session only. Its not sharable among threads. So each thread will have its own db session object and execute the query. Thats it. Nothing with hibernate CUD its all depends on how you have created your DAO / Repository objects with proper db session handling.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I exactly mean parallel execution of some CUD operation. But as I understood the synchronization in this case is provided by transactions with their own lock mechanism. Am I right?

Comment: You can do the parallel operations with hibernate but the case is different thread should use different db session (hibernate session object) and the locking and all are taken care by the DB and no worry on that.